# Return unknown output from glide-laravel

Tags: laravel, php-glide

Im using league/glide-laravel package 
and use below code to make resize image

```
    Route::get( '/showImage/{w}/{h}/{src}',function( League\Glide\Server $server,$w,$h, $src ){
    $server->outputImage( $src, [ 'w' => $w, 'h' => $h ]);
})->where( 'src', '.+');
```

but gets this result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function [`outputImage`](https://github.com/thephpleague/glide/blob/8077f529a07ded3eed6c5dcf7f688249b626ddf3/src/Server.php#L463) does not add any content-type headers to the request, so you browser does not know what to do with the data and just shows it as plain text.

It is recommended to use the function [`getImageResponse`](https://github.com/thephpleague/glide/blob/8077f529a07ded3eed6c5dcf7f688249b626ddf3/src/Server.php#L422) as this creates an actual response object with the correct headers needed to display this image in the browser.